# Why can't I dismiss the previous view on a navigation stack?

Tags: objective-c, ios, model-view-controller

This is probably going to be very obvious, but here goes.  I have two ViewControllers, one that shows the details of a person with a [+] button that opens up another ViewController that manages the edits of the Person.  When the person about to be deleted, an alert is presented and if OK is selected, the edit view should disappear and the DetailView should also disappear/transition back to the PersonsListView (not shown in code below).

I can get the EditView to dismiss, but I can't get the DetailView to dismiss as well.

Any help is appreciated.

The two ViewControllers:

```
@implementation PersonDetailViewController
...
- (void)editPerson
{
    PersonDetailEditViewController *editView = [[PersonDetailEditViewController alloc] initWithTenant:self.person];
    [editView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:editView];
    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];    
}
...
@end
```

and

```
@implementation PersonDetailEditViewController
...
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        [Person deletePerson:self.person];
        NSError *error;
        [self.person.managedObjectContext save:&error];
        [[self navigationController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        // *** HERE I ALSO WANT TO DISMISS THE DETAILVIEW ***
    }
}
...
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that PersonDetailViewController is presented in a navigation controller you should be able to do what you want by adding the following line:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```